# Creation of a button of condivision with facebook

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

Hi im working on a web site that is created with the use of frame.

The site have a map where the user can trace a route and calculate distance and the time of the route.

Now i have to do the button to share on facebook the route that user create but in the code of the sharing i put the url of the page html but this url is static so when people click on the page shared they instead to see the map with the route they see the homepage.

I already tryed to add to the url of the page the parameters of the map (pointer of location , the calculate of time and distance) but it always give me back the original url.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask questions the right way and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: _“but it always give me back the original url”_ – you need to set `og:url` meta tag to the appropriate URL.